# NSLog(@" %@",NSStringFromCGRect([(UIButton*)[array lastObject]frame]));

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

```
NSLog(@" %@",NSStringFromCGRect([(UIButton*)[array lastObject]frame]));
```

what is the error in this statement. My code is breaking
 error
[__NSArrayI frame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c5f2e00

Comment: Are you adding UIbuttons to the array ? Can you post the relevant code ?

Comment: "unrecognized selector sent" means the last object of an array will not respond to selector frame. Might be the object you are getting from an array is nil.

Comment: when i nslogged the last object i am getting the lastobject in that array

Comment: The last object in your array is another array, not a button.

Comment: Can you show code how are you adding object into array.

Comment: `[array lastObject]` seems to return an array. Try `NSLog(@"%@", [[array lastObject] class]);` to see what class it is. Misjudging what's there?

Comment: how to retrieve the last object's(last uibutton in this case) index then.

Comment: Try using `tag`. Set it when you create the button and then use it to lookup the button.

Comment: @epatel __NSArrayI-this is wat i am getting as the result of NSLog(@"%@", [[array lastObject] class]);

Comment: @user2963228 look answer below and check what you are doing wrong in code while adding button to array.

Comment: What you see there is that the last object is not an button, it's an array.

Comment: @user2963228 You've been told what the problem is (several times). The last object in `array` is another array. If this isn't what you meant to do then fix the code so the last object in `array` is the button and not another array. Post relevant code for populating `array` if you need help.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[array lastObject];

if(btn)
{

  NSLog(@" %@",NSStringFromCGRect(btn.frame));
}
```

Comment: FYI - the cast isn't needed since `lastObject` returns an `id`.

Comment: this is breaking too.